# How does account validation work?

Tags: security, authentication

Usually when you create an account to some webpage they send you an email with a link in order for you to validate your account.

If you click that link then you account is validated and thats the end of it.

How does this work?
Is that url unique for every new user so they know who visited what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a web service related question, however I can conceptually guide your through what you need to do.

When a user registers their information will probably be captured into some user table in a database somewhere. This user is marked as pending. The system can then generate a unique id i.e. a GUID which is stored next to the user entry in the database. This GUID if properly constructed will be impossible to guess. This GUID is then added as a GET parameter to the URL that you in an email to the user.

For example you might have the URL:

`http://example.com/activateuser?confirmuid=5e706449-2cbf-4938-8109-fb564c196d8f`

Thus every user will use the same URL with different confirmuid parameter. This URL will then post the confirmuid to the page where you can then use this value to look up the user in the database and then active the user or move it from a pending state to an active state.

Simple right.

Comment: I should edit the tags then. Indeed quite simple and makes sense, thanks for the answer.